# OKTA SSO Logout issue

Tags: android, authentication, okta, pkce

I am using `okta-sdk-appauth-android` library to authenticate in mobile native android app.

Login works but I have a problems with logout and next login cycle. When I am using logout method from library, in next login cycle `webview` with login screen is showing but it immediately login user without option to provide login and password manually.
Is this normal behaviour? With this kind of login, I can’t instantly login another user after logout. Only sometimes there is option to provide login & password… What it depends on? Can I force providing login & password after every logout?
Even after my access and refresh tokens expires it automatically login user. I am using native app configuration + `PKCE`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem as follows:

- Call webAuthClient.signOutOfOkta(Activity) as soon as you press the logout button.
- Result will be returned in ResultCallback, you will see whether it is logged in or not.
- Call webAuthClient.sessionClient.clear()

Like this :

```java
webAuthClient.registerCallback(object : ResultCallback<AuthorizationStatus, AuthorizationException> {
            override fun onCancel() {
                network_progress.hide()
                showMessage(getString(R.string.operation_cancelled))
            }

            override fun onError(msg: String?, exception: AuthorizationException?) {
                signInError(msg, exception)
            }

            override fun onSuccess(result: AuthorizationStatus) {
                network_progress.hide()
                when (result) {
                    AUTHORIZED -> signInSuccess()
                    SIGNED_OUT -> webAuthClient.sessionClient.clear()
                }
            }
        }, this)
```